# Maintain sitecore items in repository in jss sitecore first approach like Unicorn, Jss-cli OR TDS

Tags: jss, tds, unicorn

Hi I am using Sitecore jss with sitecore first approach. My sample solution is under here [sitecore.first-jss-helix.git](https://github.com/andiappan-ar/sitecore.first-jss-helix.git).

Currently i am maintaining in repository all my sitecore related content items as sitecore package like here [Package-folder](https://github.com/andiappan-ar/sitecore.first-jss-helix/tree/master/Sitecore%20Packages)
But i need a standard way like Unicorn or TDS.

My question below,

1. Can we use unicorn for jss , since its using dlls and config files?
   If possible please guide.
2. Do we have any option in jss-cli or some other approach to convert all my sitecore items(template, media layout , rendering place holders) to yml files as its in sample applications.
   If it converts then i will maintain it in repository like that and other users can deploy sitecore items using jss-cli cmd(jss deploy app -c -d) to thier local machine.
3. Hope TDS is possible but i need to have solution in separate , since its a .net base template project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure, you can use Unicorn or TDS with JSS. Nothing special. just as normal create a Visual studio solution, project. And configer Unicorn.

When you use Unicorn you can do a Sync to (reg)enerate all yml files.
See the Automated Deployment section of the Unicorn documentation for all the scripted options you have: https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn basically call the /unicorn.aspx with the correct parameters

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jan.

I had implemented using unicorn like below[(Url for implementation)](https://github.com/andiappan-ar/sitecore.first-jss-helix/tree/master/Serialization/JSS.Serialization/JSS.Serialization),

Since we are using Java script solution for sitecore jss we cant have unicorn solution here. So i have included one more folder under repository and created new C# project called serialization.

[image]

Then i installed unicorn nuget packages into the respective solution.

Then i had introduce my custom unicorn config like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sc.variable name="JssUnicornSerializeRootFolder" value="D:\Aga\Git New\JssReactWeb\src" />
    <unicorn>
      <configurations>
        <!--Feature layer-->
        <configuration name="JSS.Feature">
          <targetDataStore physicalRootPath="$(JssUnicornSerializeRootFolder)\Feature\Serialization" />
          <predicate type="Unicorn.Predicates.SerializationPresetPredicate, Unicorn" singleInstance="true">
            <!--Templates-->
            <include name="Template-Feature" database="master" path="/sitecore/templates/Feature" />
            <!--Media-->
            <include name="Media" database="master" path="/sitecore/media library/Feature" />
            <!--Rendering-->
            <include name="Rendering" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Feature" />
          </predicate>
        </configuration>

        <!--Foundation layer-->
        <!--<configuration name="JSS.Foundation">
          <targetDataStore physicalRootPath="$(JssUnicornSerializeRootFolder)\Foundation\Serialization" />
          <predicate type="Unicorn.Predicates.SerializationPresetPredicate, Unicorn" singleInstance="true">
          </predicate>
        </configuration>-->

        <!--Project layer-->
        <configuration name="JSS.Project">
          <targetDataStore physicalRootPath="$(JssUnicornSerializeRootFolder)\Project\Serialization" />
          <predicate type="Unicorn.Predicates.SerializationPresetPredicate, Unicorn" singleInstance="true">
            <!--Templates-->
            <include name="Template-Project" database="master" path="/sitecore/templates/Project/Commercial Tenants" />
            <!--Layout-->
            <include name="Layout" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/Layouts/Project/Commercial Tenants" />
            <!--Rendering-->
            <include name="SubLayoutRendering" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Project/Commercial Tenants" />
            <!--Placeholder-->
            <include name="Placeholder" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings/Project/Commercial Tenants" />
            <!--Content-->
            <include name="Content" database="master" path="/sitecore/content/All Sites" />
          </predicate>

        </configuration>

      </configurations>
    </unicorn>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Then i publish my solution to hosted sitecore cm. Then i can able re-serialize all the sitecore items on first time and i can maintain now in my repository.